# Inkscape: Sharp Sloped Edges

Tags: inkscape

Is there an easy way to transform a standard box or rectangle to look like this?

[image: Sample image]

I am referring to the sharp sloped orange box in the picture. As far as I know, one can only install round edges. With "easy way", I mean a method without subtracting shapes or carefully aligning the nodes. Maybe some filter?

Answer (score 3):

Simple method

1. Draw two rectangles with hold ctrl

[image]

2. Select two rectangles and align it

[image]

3. With both selected rect go to main menu - path - intersection
4. Right click on new object - Fill and Stroke
5. Set fill to none and stroke to what you want

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you want the angles to cut 20px into the corners of rectangle measuring 200px x 100px.

1. First create the 200px x 100px rectangle using the rectangle tool. Specify in the options that you want rounded corners of 20px.
2. Return to the selection tool (F1) and from the menu select "Path" -> "Object to Path".
3. Select the node tool (F2) and then select all of the nodes by dragging the mouse over them.
4. Double click the node button called "Make selected nodes corner" (7th button in).

That should transform the rounded edges to square edges are you are looking for.

Comment: it's even simpler, than i'm described )

Comment: @sergeydyadyul the question states "I mean a method without subtracting shapes or carefully aligning the nodes", which is basically what your method describes. My method allows the user to specify the size of the bevel accurately, uses no additional shapes and does not rely on aligning objects.